# I'm sending message in gmail via phpmailer, containing a link that will redirect on my php page in localhost(xampp)

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, phpmailer

I'm sending message in gmail via phpmailer, containing a link that will redirect on my php page in localhost(xampp). But it wasn't able to redirect on my php page in my localhost. **Here's my code linking my localhost page**

```
  $mail->isHTML(true);                         // Set email format to HTML
  $mail->Subject = 'MilkBank Account Verification';
  $mail->Body    = 'Click the link to verify your account.<br>  
 <a href="http:localhost//MilkBank2.0/UserPages/BackEnd/verify.be.update" >Register Account!! </a>';

  $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

  $mail->send();
```

Is it possible to redirect it?

Comment: P.S I was able to send it on gmail but the problem is redirecting the sent message that is containing a link to my localhost php page

Comment: `http:localhost` should be `http://localhost`. I assume you know that `localhost` is only going to work on your local computer though.

Comment: I assume you know that a link to localhost will only work for you, and not anyone else you send the link to.

Comment: yes i'm sending it only on my email account which i can access on my local computer

Comment: Did you try changing what I suggested? If yes, did it work or what happened? If no, why not?

Answer (score -1):

Simply add if-else tag

```
if ($mail->Send()) 
{ 
    header("Location:Yourfile.php");//echo "Message Sent!";            
}

else
{
   echo "Message could not be sent.  ";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit; 
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely not an answer to the question. They do not want to redirect elsewhere after _sending_ the mail, this is about a link contained in the email.